# Can I have a page of my app without a layout on Android?

Tags: android, layout

I'm comming from IOS development and I probably have a lot of vicious while developing this app for Android.

When I was on IOS, I had a lot of viewcontroller without a visual file (I never used storyboards).
Every screen of the app was behind coded.
I want to know if I can do the same in Android. I have an option to not use the visual class?

Btw, I know my question can be confuse. Sorry for that

Thanks anyway

Comment: I think your nomenclature may be confusing here.  Are you asking can you have an Activity who's UI isn't in an xml file?  Yes, although except for very few cases it is NOT recommended-  the xml files are MUCH easier to read and manipulate, a UI in code is a maintenance nightmare.  Its usually only done when the entire UI is decided at runtime from a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The typical approach is to use an XML file and call

`setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);`

to assign that view to the Activity but you could also create your view programmatically and use the same function on a `View` java object.

[This tutorial explains how in more detail](http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html)

Comment: Can you be more specific about how can I create it programmatically?

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes Updated with a link to a tutorial. Hope that helps

Comment: Amazing Carl! Exactly what I was looking for. thanks